# use advanced calculations in the database or let client application perform

Tags: mysql, c, stored-procedures, calculation

I'm designing to use a mysql database in our product and replace bin-files.
We use a complex chemical calculations with a raw data array containing 1024 posts adding configuration values to extract clean (-er) content-values
This means we remove distracting background information to present a clean graph of the substance contents.

Today the raw-data is sent to an app and result is calculated, then registration is performed.
Plan is that the raw data is to be entered in the database and the result shall also be entered there after calculation.

My question is if this is something that a mysql database would perform better than a client application design for it. ie shall I make the effort to convert or not?
Pros and cons?

Comment: 'complex chemical calculations' - you should maybe check out maths functions in mysql to see if it can even be done in mysql

Comment: thks, never though about it, shall check it out